# Zonal Statistics doesn't work after updating processing (2.10.2)

Tags: qgis, zonal-statistics, qgis-processing

After updating the processing tool zonal statistics doesn't work.

> in method 'SpatialReference_ImportFromProj4', argument 2 of type 'char *

Could someone else try if it's a bug or just an issue on my PC.

Answer (score 1):

not just you.

Works fine with this setup (Ubuntu 32-bit, QGIS 2.10.1)

```
Installed version: 2.9.0 (in /home/steven/.qgis2/python/plugins/processing)
Available version: 2.10.2 (in QGIS Official Plugin Repository)
```

I get the same error when in processing 20.10.2

You can try using the 'downgrade plugin' option (and it still works from the Raster Menu, just not from Processing). Or you can [download 2.9.0 from here](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/processing/version/2.9.0/). It's worth having a VM to try out upgrades away from your main setup!

Might want to raise a ticket on the [Qgis Issues log](https://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues), doesn't seem to have been raised.

Comment: Sould I open a ticket?

Comment: it would be useful - you can sign up [here on OSGeo](http://www.osgeo.org/osgeo_userid). The latest version is only 4 days old so you may well be the first person to notice :)

Comment: Ticket is online.